# when to use pointers in function arguments in c, UART function

Tags: c, pointers, uart

I'm reading some example code for a uart on a microcontroller.

In the header file for the uart libary there is the following function definition.

Then in the main program the following code is called.

My question is why do they use a pointer as a function argument?

Alternatively, the UART write function declaration below does not use a pointer.

I'm just wondering why and when to use pointers.

Many thanks

Comment: You need a [tag:c] book. This is very broad for SO.

Comment: Your alternative can only write a single byte per call.  That is okayish, it will not be fast.  Device driver calls usually have significant overhead, you pay for that for each individual call.  Albeit that this is not usually much of a concern on a micro-controller.  You need a pointer and a count to write more than a single byte per call.

Comment: Great help everyone, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main function, the `BANNER` is cast as a `uint8_t*` because it is a string literal and as such has type `const char[]` that decays as `const char*` when used in a expression or passed as a function.  `char` and `uint8_t` are different types, although their representation is identical and only the interpretation of certain values differ.

There is another problem in the `main` function:  you should pass `strlen(BANNER)` instead of `sizeof(BANNER)` so as not to include the null terminator in the count of bytes to transmit.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#define BANNER  "Hello, world!\n\n"

int main(void) {
    ti_uart_write_buffer(TI_UART_0, (const uint8_t *)BANNER, strlen(BANNER));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you have to use a pointer because `ti_uart_write_buffer` sends an array of data.

For performance reasons, there is no way to pass an array by value to a C function. Because doing so would involve making a copy of the data, which would waste both execution time and memory. So this is made impossible by the C language itself.

Instead, you can pass a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: As an analogy: you own a car shop and you wish to hire someone to clean all the cars. Would you then drive every single car in the shop over to his place and ask him to clean them, or would you give him the address to the car shop and tell him to go do the work there?

Answer (score 0):

In the function description it is seen that it is a multi-byte data write function. Hence, when you want to write multiple bytes you send a pointer to that data.
On the other hand, if you want to write only one byte, use function which takes only one byte, which is passed by value.